# How to split a CSV file such that first column stays?

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I have a 100K line csv file of the following format:

```
ID1, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
ID2, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
ID3, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
ID4, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
```

This needs to be converted into the following format:

```
ID1,  attribute-1
ID1,  attribute-2
ID1, ..
ID2,  attribute-1
ID2,  attribute-2
ID2, ..
ID3,  attribute-1
ID3,  attribute-2
ID3, ..
ID4,  attribute-1
ID4,  attribute-2
ID4, ..
....
```

I know that this can be done using the normal cut and parse each line. But is there an easier way to do this? Please help.

Comment: please add some rows in the input file, some rows with the values, and then explain how to put them in the output. In your example there are only field names

Comment: Thanks, @aborruso; I have done the needful to make it clear.

Comment: ok than please look at my reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/58330927/757714

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is simple csv with no commas embedded in quoted fields or the like to complicate things,

```
perl -F, -lane '$c1 = shift @F; print "$c1,$_" for @F' input.csv
```

should do it. Takes the first column of each line, and for each other column, prints that first one and the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
$ cat vivek 
ID1, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
ID2, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
ID3, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
ID4, attribute-1, attribute-2,..
```

does the following work for you?

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1",",$i}}' vivek
ID1,  attribute-1
ID1,  attribute-2
ID1, ..
ID2,  attribute-1
ID2,  attribute-2
ID2, ..
ID3,  attribute-1
ID3,  attribute-2
ID3, ..
ID4,  attribute-1
ID4,  attribute-2
ID4, ..
```

It iterates over the fields in each line, printing the first one, plus the one under the iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much, @tink; this works exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), starting from

```
ID1,attribute-1,attribute-2,attribute-3,attribute-4,attribute-5
ID2,attribute-1,attribute-2,attribute-3,attribute-4,attribute-5
```

and running

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," reshape -r '^[^1]$' -o k,v then cut -x -f k input.txt
```

you will have

```
ID1,attribute-1
ID1,attribute-2
ID1,attribute-3
ID1,attribute-4
ID1,attribute-5
ID2,attribute-1
ID2,attribute-2
ID2,attribute-3
ID2,attribute-4
ID2,attribute-5
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple with `awk`. You can just loop from `2 -> NF` outputting the first field followed by the current on each line, e.g.

```
awk -F", " -v OFS=", " '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your sample data, that would produce:

```
$ awk -F", " -v OFS=", " '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' file
ID, attribute-1
ID, attribute-2
ID, ...
```